# error instalar express

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, npm

Tengo este problema, cada vez que intento instalar **express** en **windows 10** con el comando `npm install express` o `npm install express-generator` me sale este error:

```
 npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\PC\Documents\proyectos_practica\node_practice\package.json'
npm WARN node_practice No description
npm WARN node_practice No repository field.
npm WARN node_practice No README data
npm WARN node_practice No license field.
```

ya tengo agregado las variables al path, ¿alguien sabe que puede ser?
gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1):

¿Tienes creado el Package.json con las dependencias que vas a usar, dentro de la carpeta del proyecto?

El estándar viene definido en:
[Package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json)

Así, en lugar de instalar todas las librerías una a una, tan solo tienes que usar:

```
    npm install
```

Además, como ha indicado el compañero **Vicente Almea** también puedes instalar librerías de forma global, añadiendo al comando **-g**, por ejemplo:

```
    npm install -g nodemon
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda. Saludos!

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, lo que pasa es que yo varias veces lo pude instalar localmente y sin necesidad de crear el package.json pero ahora me arroja ese error y no se porque

Answer (score 1):

realmente si creo que deberias tener `package.json` para poder instalar algo con `npm`, te sugiero que antes de empezar cualquier projecto uses `npm init`, luego facilmente podras instalar cualquier modulo usando `npm install`. Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es porque no tienes un `package.json` en el proyecto, para instalar express con express-generator tienes que instalarlo global primero:

`npm install --global express-generator`

despues puedes usar el comando `express` para crear un proyecto express, el cual te crea una aplicacion con package.json y lo necesario para comenzar, solo tienes que instalar las dependencias que faltan con `npm install`, y despues `npm start` para correr la aplicacion

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que instalarlo global:

```
nmp install -g express-generator
```

Answer (score 0):

Sigue los siguientes pasos:

- Crea el `index.js`
- Después, usa el comando `npm int` para crear el `package.json`

Y te da error después al instalar *express*, lo que hice fue eliminar el *package.json* e instalar *express* y automáticamente se genera el *package.json*

Y tendría que funcionar

Answer (score 0):

1.- `npm init -y`

2.- `npm install express`

Comment: Falta explicacion, tenes varias respuestas muy pobres de contenido.